# OnePlus one stuck in CyanogenMOD recovery CM13

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, stock-rom

I wanted to factory reset my OnePlus one to its factory settings. My OnePlus one is completely stock, no bootloader unlocked and no USB debugging enabled.
After the factory reset was completed the phone rebooted itself, it entered recovery mode and there was no way out of there, it would just boot back to recovery. Just before it enters recovery mode it shows and android error for a split second; "No Command"

-I did a factory reset from within the recovery menu, took a long time but didn't work, still only the recovery menu.

-I wiped the cache, didn't work.

-Then I installed the SDK kit on my Windows PC, got ADB working and entered the sideload option in the recovery menu. Sended the latest CM13 Beacon zip to the phone. It told me that it was installing but after completion it just disconnects from ADB and shows the Recovery screen. Navigating to "Apply Update" and then instead of "Apply from ADB" I can also pick: "Choose from emulated" but that just sends me back to the main menu.

Rebooting, rebooting to bootloader, it all gives me the Cyanogen Recovery screen

Comment: That's why one should unlock the bootloader first after purchase... Pull data from phone via ADB if possible, then unlock bootloader (wiping data in the progress) and flash TWRP. Stay the hell away from Cyanogen Recovery.

Comment: I unlocked the bootloader and the phone booted directly to Android. Weird but everythings works fine now